# Hide function input parameters in C# web-service?

Tags: c#, web-services, user-input

I have a question regarding if it is possible to hide inputs to a web-service method.

Lets say that the fourth parameter takes a password as input, and we want this input only to be used on the client side.

The function has 4 input parameters, and is there any way possible to still have all the input parameters to the function but make the fourth parameter invisible when accessing the .asmx file through the web-browser? This is to eliminate users trying to access the service and trying to input random data.

[image: Parameter input in C# web service.]

**EDIT:** To place this in an example.

We have an iPhone application, when a user makes use of a function, some parameters are sent to the web-service along with the fourth parameter that should contain a key of some sort to validate that the user is on an actual iPhone using the application and not someone accessing the web-service trying to access data.

```
public someVariable someFunction(someVar parameter1,someVar parameter2,someVar parameter3,someVar parameter4)
{

    if (key.isMatch(parameter4))
    {

       The user is on an iPhone using the app : Proceeding.

    }
    else
       The user is not on an iPhone, cancelling function.

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can prevent calling your method from webbrowser,by extending SoapExtension and getting extra information as soapheader ,that just can be send by enduser app

have a look to this [Using SOAP Header and SOAP Extensions in a Web Service](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sovonnath/SOAPHeaderandSOAPExtensionsinaWebService11162005021034AM/SOAPHeaderandSOAPExtensionsinaWebService.aspx)

Comment: @DeveloperX Do you possibly have an url pointing me in the right direction, because i'm very unfamiliar with C# services as our main focus is iPhone programming. Would be really helpful.

Comment: i meant you can get extra information from endu ser(Iphone app) when calls the webservice,and webservice always expects this extra information and whenever it doesnt present you can reject request

Comment: Are you looking for very simple sample?

Comment: the question was made quite stressfully, the thing that happens is that the fourth parameter is not something the user inputs at all, it's a static key that is generated from the user's iPhone and is sent with all the requests to the service. And we want to hide the input parameter in the .asmx file which can be reached from a web browser.

Comment: did you read the link i put here? it can help you to solve your problem

Comment: Yes, i did, and i realized that i have a soap-based web-service. But i'm not at liberty to make huge changes to the service.

Comment: cant you make any change in webservice?

Answer (score 0):

The interface that you are using was not supposed to be used for anything but testing.

If you need to use it on production you should rather implement your own page, so the TextBox for parameter 4 would be masked.